# Will %XP items increase all of the XP you gain?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I found a pretty handy little necklace while playing *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning*. It looks a little something like this:

[image]

*Now* this little gem has me wondering:

**Does the Experience Bonus count toward *all* experience earned (Quests, kills, lockpicking, dispelling, etc.)?**

Comment: I would guess it is for all XP gained, but it's hard to say. You could try saving, turn in a quest, and then reload and turn it in without the necklace equipped to see if the XP gained is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it stacks as a "+" and is not multiplied.  An example is if you have four items granting +1% exp then you will get a total of +4% exp.  Keep in mind that items like this are useless after level 36 and should be substituted with something more effective in combat.  The max level is level 40 but the bonuses received in skills and abilities or miniscule.

Edit:

Exp bonuses apply to all sources (dispelling, lockpicking, quests, defeating enemies, etc,...).  I have consumed exp potions to defeat enemies and simultaneously receive bonus exp from finishing a quest.  By applying Reckoning mode and exp bonus potions you can gain about 30k exp multiple times in the game.

Comment: The question is not whether it stacks, but rather what sources actually gain the bonus.

Comment: my apologies, From my observation it appears that everything gets the bonus and this includes exp potions.

Comment: Then you should put that in the main body of the answer! :)

Comment: I am new here and never planned to participate.  I just happen to really enjoy this stupid game.  Thanks!  :)